# Modify each item in observable of array asynchronously and return modified observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am building a service in Angular using ngrx that looks for a list of messages in the store. Once it has the list, it needs to fetch some asynchronous data for each message, and define a new object (ModifiedMessage). The service should return an observable with the list of modified messages.

My attempt:

```
getMessages(): Observable<ModifiedMessage[]> {
        return combineLatest(
          this.store.select(MessageSelectors.getListOfMessages),
        ).pipe(
          map(([messages]) => {
            return messages.map(message => {
              return this.store
                .select(MessageSelectors.getUserForMessage(message.userId))
                .pipe(
                  take(1),
                  map(user => {

                    return new ModifiedMessage({
                      id: message.id,
                      user: user.name,
                    });
                  })
                );
            });
          })
        );
      }
```

This is not working as TypeScript complains I am returning Observable[]> and not Observable[]>.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend building a selector to get the modified messages because it keeps the state selection logic out of your service.

For example:

```
// ...
static getListOfModifiedMessages = createSelector(
  MessageSelectors.getListOfMessages,
  MessageSelectors.getUsers,
  (messages, users) => {
    return messages.map(({ id, userId }) =>
    {
      const { name } = users.find(user => user.id === message.userId);
      return new ModifiedMessage({ id, name });
    });
  }
);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks that is good advice, unfortunately I oversimplified my example but I also need to fetch data from an API which is not in the store so using selectors won't solve the issue. So I still would like to know how to achieve it without changing the logic to use selectors. Thanks